# Running script from cmd for bluetooth connection

Tags: python, bluetooth

my project requires data transfer with android app via bluetooth. I’ve tested the code by running it in thonny and it works fine. Since I want to run the script as soon as raspberry pi boots up, I ran the script via cmd (rc.local).

This is how Ì ran my python code

```
sudo python3 /home/desktop/rpi.py &
```

The scrpit does run, but it won’t let me connect to the raspberry pi. I use bluedot library for the bluetooth. Assuming code is already running, and device has been paired, this is how the connection supposed to be.

```
Open App -> Press button -> Connection to Rpi
```

Is there anything I can do regarding this? Thank you.

Comment: You say "The scrpit does run, but it won’t let me connect to the raspberry pi". Can you update your question with some more information about what you have done to confirm your script is running normally when started by `rc.local`?  I would suggest that you don't use `rc.local`, here is a good blog post on an alternative: https://blog.usedbytes.com/2019/11/run-at-startup-without-rc.local/

Comment: If you want us to debug some random python program you at least need to include a minimal example that show the script and some diagnostics (even if it's just "print ('fooo')" statements) to show how it's failing. Remember that rc.local is owned and run by root and has a different environment to your Thonny debugging session.